# how to add new column with string constant in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

How to add a string value to a column in pyspark. 
Using withColumn("status","online") gives error

I'm using Spark 1.6 here

Answer (score -1):

A new column can be added like below

```
df.withColumn("status",df.online)
```

This can be casted to string type explicitly like below

```
df.withColumn("status",df.online.cast("String"))
```